# why resubmit after refresh page

Tags: php, submit, refresh, form-submit, page-refresh

why resubmit after refresh page

go to http://qass.im/message-envelope/

and upload any file but only ext "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "zip", "pdf", "docx", "rar", "txt"

after uploaded click F5 button to refresh page

now resubmit and file be upload again!

why?

I want disable resubmit after upload file without jquery

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "zip", "pdf", "docx", "rar", "txt", "doc");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$newname = $extension.'_'.substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 7)), 4, 7);
$imglink = 'attachment/attachment_file_';
$uploaded = $imglink .$newname.'.'.$extension;
if ((($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/msword")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "text/plain")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/x-rar-compressed")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/x-zip-compressed")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/zip")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "multipart/x-zip")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/x-compressed")
|| ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "application/octet-stream"))
&& ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] < 5242880) // Max size is 5MB
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{   
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"],
$uploaded );
echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$uploaded.'">click</a>';
echo '<h3>'.$uploaded.'</h3>';
}
if($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"] > 0){
echo '<h3>Please choose file to upload it!</h3>'; // If you don't choose file
}
elseif(!in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
echo '<h3>This extension is not allowed!</h3>'; // If you choose file not allowed
}
elseif($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["size"] > 5242880){
echo "Big size!"; // If you choose big file
}

    unset($_FILE); //add these two lines
    unset($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of your browser. If you made a POST request and hit F5 the browser tries to resubmit the post request and therefore your Image and your form data will be submited again.

One solution is that you make a refresh of the page from PHP as GET request.

```
header('Location: /yoururl'); // May use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ;)
exit;
```

This only works when no content had been send to the output buffer. The exit after the command is also very important to stop script execution.

Comment: What exaclty is the problem? Can you show me how you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to refresh the page after the file has been uploaded. Add the following code just after **move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploaded );**

```
$page = "http://yoururl.com/upload.php?uploaded&url=".$uploaded;
$sec = "1";
header("Location: $page");
```

and add the following code at the end of the **PHP** code of the question :

```
if(isset($_GET['uploaded'])){
 $uploaded=$_GET['url'];
 echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$uploaded.'">click</a>';
 echo '<h3>'.$uploaded.'</h3>';
}
```

So that the user would also get a **file uploaded** message.